# C# Parsing acquired address to an IP address

Tags: c#, parsing, ip

New to programming but attempting to self teach myself some areas that school hasn't shown me as of yet.

The grand scheme of the project which is up and working is to accept client connections to a server. In a console window, it will display the time of connection. I'm trying to also to get it display the clients IP address for logging sake. The following is what I have, but I can't get it to parse correctly.

```
//Console Output
string IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString();
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
Console.WriteLine("New TCP connection made at " + "{0:g}", DateTime.Now + IPAddress);
```

If I leave out the "IPAddress address......" line, it will display the long ugly, unparsed address =p

Comment: can you show the 'the long ugly, unparsed address'? :D

Comment: New TCP connection made at 2/5/2013 10:55:46 PMfe80::c139:f627:29c3:29d1%10

Comment: [Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1574373.aspx/1)

Comment: Are you sure you are just not confusing IPv6 addresses to be ugly?

Comment: Shouldn't be using IPv6, as I'm using my local machine, and connecting with the client app locally as well....

Comment: Thats not a valid assumption. You should add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at all IP addresses from the address list and discard the IPV6 ones.

```
IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
    Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
    a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily%28VS.80%29.aspx) for AddressFamily types.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to also to get it display the clients IP address for
>   logging sake.

Keep in mind that there may be multiple NICs on a client, i.e., wired/wireless (as well as more than wired NIC). This means there will be more than one IP address and most likely a mix of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

When using the [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, passing an empty string as the host name will return the IPv4 addresses of the local host:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry( string.Empty );
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry( Dns.GetHostName() );
```

Then, to find all of the addresses, use the [AddressFamily Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily.aspx):

```
var addresses = entry.AddressList.Where( x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork );
```

Where `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` = Address for IP version 4.

From here, you can iterate through the `addresses` as needed.

Comment: Trying to see if I can get it to work with the supplied suggestions. Still very new to some stuff so it takes me a little bit to figure things out :/